# ggplot2 barplot with gradient color fill in one or few bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, gradient

I have made a barplot using ggplot and filled the bars with some random colours but it seems that I am unable to fill a specific bar with gradient colour (for example from green to blue).

My current code is

```r
x1<-c('A','B','C','B','A','A','B','A','C','A','A','B','C')

x2<-c('G1','G1','G1','G2','G3','G3','G4','G4','G5','G6','G6','G6','G7')

x3<-c(2,3,3.5,4,6,5,5.4,3,4.1,2.5,.2,1.7,1.9)

x4<-c('a','b','a','b','a','b','a','a','b','a','b','b','b')

Data<-cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4)

Data<-data.frame(Data)

ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=x2, y=x3, fill=x1, color=x4)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6, position=position_dodge())+ 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','red','green','purple'))
```

which generates the attached graph. I am trying to fill the green bars with a colour scale, for example, from green to blue. I do not need to change the colours of the other bars.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not related to your issue but: that's a really convoluted way to make a data frame. You can just use: `Data = data.frame(x1 = c(value1, value2, ...), x2 = c(value3, value4, ...), ...)`. See `?data.frame.`

Comment: Another possibly not related issue: The plot generally looks odd. For example, `x1 = A` and `x1 = B` have the same fill colour. Then there are different `fill` and `colour` mappings. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What would the gradient fill represent? I get the feeling from the question that there might be possibly a conceptual misunderstanding of ggplots aesthetics - they are usually used to visualise dimensions and not just to create a fancy fill for your plots. However, If you are indeed intending to show a dimension, probably `geom_bar` might not be what you are looking for - maybe `geom_tile` or `geom_raster`?

Comment: Thanks @neilfws. I just wanted to create a data frame example, and of course, your comment applies to avoid convolution!

Comment: Thanks MauritsEvers and @Tjebo for the replies. Yes, the plot looks a bit odd but that's really what I want. x1 refers to a categorical variable and for some reasons, I have to use the same colour when it takes on A and B. x3 can be seen as -log(p-value), and x2 is another categorical variable. For the green bars, I want to make the colour vary from green to another colour (blue for example). This could be seen as part of a heatmap which I am trying to represent while combining with my other variables. I appreciate Tjebo for introducing me gemo_raster and gemo_tile, and I need to check them.